# Swapping variables' values concisely using C++

Tags: c++, logic

How can I swap the values of two variables ?

This works, but I'd would prefer a one liner :

```
int a = 10, b = 30;
a = a + b;
b = a - b;
a = a - b;
```

Comment: Are you under the mistaken impression that using another variable costs more than not using one?

Comment: How about the XORSWAP macro from the [Wikipedia page](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm) on XOR Swap algorithm? Make a note to read the section about why it should be avoided in practice ;)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps that's cheating but there's simply :

```
std::swap(a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::tie(x,y) = std::make_pair(y,x);
```

But `std::swap(x,y)` is much more readable and probably more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
int x = 10, y = 10;
y = (x + y)-y;
}
```

Solved a little bit but not completely but solved if you use this code

```
int swap(int *x, int y){
*x = (*x + *y) - *x;
return 0;
}

int main()
{
int x = 10;
int y = 5;
y = (x + y) - y + swap(&x, &y);
cout << x << endl << y << endl;
}
```